# Treating Rails model subclass at superclass level: simplified routing and single controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, polymorphism

I've currently got:

```
class Tutorial
  has_many :comments
end

class VideoTutorial < Tutorial
end

class Comments
  belongs_to :tutorial
end
```

`routes.rb` reads like:

```
resources :tutorials do
  resources :comments
end
```

I'd like to be able to refer to specific types of `Tutorial` (starting with `VideoTutorial`) like this:

```
/tutorials/1234
/tutorials/1234/comments/new
/tutorials/1234/comments/6374
```

Which means dealing with tutorials as `Tutorial` as much as possible, rather than `VideoTutorial` (or other subclasses as they come along).

I would like to have all calls going to a single controller and using straightforward routing as above.

**PROBLEM: what is happening now**

My forms seem to be matching routes polymorphically, matching the type of a specific `Tutorial` instance, e.g.

```
# @tutorial is a VideoTutorial
= form_for @tutorial do |f|  # undefined method 'video_tutorial_path'
...
```

Which is pretty cool but not what I'm looking for in this situation :)

I am currently making things work by generating those routes:

```
resources :tutorials do
  resources :comments
end

resources :video_tutorials, :controller => "tutorials" do
  resources :comments
end
```

I'm directing to the `Tutorials` controller as I'd like to avoid lots of controllers multiplying, when new `Tutorial` subclasses arise.

But this gets messy:

- You get a lot of extra routes
- You get more routes when you add a new subclass of `Tutorial`
- You end up referencing params like `:video_tutorial_id` rather than just a generic `:id`

I'd like to treat all types of `Tutorial` as `Tutorial` in the above scenario.

What's a simpler, less messy approach?

**UPDATE: as per @jdl's suggestion**

Link to `Tutorial` show page:

```
  # original approach:
  = link_to 'Show', @tutorial

  # now:
  = link_to 'Show', tutorial_path(@tutorial)
```

`form_for` helper:

```
  # original approach:
  = form_for @tutorial do |f|

  # now:
  = form_for @tutorial, :as => :tutorial, :url => tutorial_path do |f|
```

`form_for` nested resources:

```
  # original approach:
  = form_for [@tutorial, @new_comment] do |f|

  # now:
  = form_for [@tutorial, @new_comment], :as => :tutorial, :url => tutorial_comments_path(@tutorial, @new_comment) do |f|
```

This works as intended now.

A bit more wordy :) Any further thoughts as to making it more elegant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `:as` parameter of `form_for`.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

Comment: Thanks @jdl, based on your suggested solution, I updated my original question with a revised approach where it now works